# Display an error message if an invalid number is entered

Tags: c#, .net

I have a menu screen in WinForms with options from 1-8.

You may find below the method KeyDown:

```
        private void Form2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3();
            f3.ShowDialog();
        }

        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D2)
        {
            Form4 f4 = new Form4();
            f4.ShowDialog();
        }

        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D3)
        {
            Form5 f5 = new Form5();
            f5.ShowDialog();
        }

        (...)

        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D8)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

What should I do to display an error message if an invalid number is entered?
Thanks.

Comment: Well you should decide how that should look...should some text just appear within the form? Should there be a modal dialog? Once you determine that, you can research how to do it in the chosen framework.

Comment: You can use 'else' after all the 'else if', but it's better to use 'swich case'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `else` after all the `else if` to do `MessageBox.Show()` with the error message?

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm beginner. Thanks for the solution.